# Renaming selected columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to rename selected columns (say the two las columns) in my data frame using the `iloc` and `df.columns` functions but it does not seem to work for me and I can't figure out why. Here is a toy example of what I want to achieve:

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'one': list(range(5)),
     'two': list(range(5)),
     'three': list(range(5)),
     'four': list(range(5)),
     'five': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
     'six': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df.iloc[:,-2:].columns = ['letter_1','letter_2']

df.columns
```

but I keep getting the original columns' names:

```py
Index(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'], dtype='object')
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `df.columns=list(df.iloc[:,:-2].columns)+['letter_1','letter_2']`

Comment: NOTICE:  "the two last columns" of a df created by a `dict` is not well defined in python versions earlier than 3.7 (or 3.6 as a CPython impl detail), as dicts prior to that did not grantee order of keys.

Comment: @Adam.Er8 I thought that once I convert a dictionary to data frame the locations of columns are fixed. If that is not the case, how can `iloc` work?

Comment: it won't work on `df.columns` for a df created from a dict in Python 3.5 and earlier. Specifically in CPython 3.5, you'll get the columns sorted by alphabetical order

Comment: @anky_91 That worked! I guess I can't change the names by subseting data frame like I tried but overwriting the names I want to change works just fine. Thank you!

Comment: @Furqan Hashim I saw the question you linked as possible duplicate but as far as I can tell all answers there were relying on using names in one way or another and I needed a solution that uses only columns location (unless I missed something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use [`df.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html):

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'one': list(range(5)),
     'two': list(range(5)),
     'three': list(range(5)),
     'four': list(range(5)),
     'five': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
     'six': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
     }

new_names = ['letter_1', 'letter_2']
df = pd.DataFrame(d).rename(index=str, columns=dict(zip(list(d.keys())[-len(new_names):], new_names)))

print(df.columns)
```

Output:

> Index(['letter_1', 'four', 'one', 'letter_2', 'three', 'two'], dtype='object')

Comment: That won't work - it requires me to use the names of the columns I want to rename and there is quite a few of them - that's why I am trying to use the location-based renaming. I want to rename a couple of last columns with long names and for multiple data frames so I don't want to use the names directly.

Comment: @Justyna then what about `df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns[-2:],['letter_1','letter_2'])))`

Comment: OK, edited my answer, this will infer the amount of columns to replace by the length of the `new_names` list

Comment: @Adam.Er8 The slice should be `[-len(new_names):]` -- then it will do what I need. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, correct... my bad :)

Comment: I would also use `df_main.columns` rather than `d.keys()` because the data frame I work with is modified after I import the raw dictionary data.